# SOCK_PACKET in Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, network-programming

Is there any alternative for SOCK_PACKET in windows?
I am trying to construct an arp packet without libraries like winpcap.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use raw sockets: `SOCK_RAW`. When sending ARP packets you'll probably need `AF_PACKET` (the address family, not the socket type) though.

Comment: The differnce between SOCK_RAW and SOCK_PACKET in UNIX is that you can send on the "Ethernet Level", is this the same thing? Anyway, I've very much to do, and this is a private project of mine - so I'll just test it later. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Windows has a [`SendARP()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366358.aspx) function for sending ARP requests.